# Asynchronous Javascript Recursion

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm not sure how to ask the question rattling around in my head right now, so bear with me.  I'm brand new to asynchronous programming, and I figured the best way to learn would be to make a little javascript pong game.  I started with a shootball() function and just bounce a div around another div.  How I did this was with something like this:

```
function shootball(angle, speed){
    angle = (angle/360.0)*2*Math.PI;
    var ballmotion = setInterval(function(){
        var nowx, nowy, minusY, plusX;
        nowx = $("#ball").position().left;
        nowy = $("#ball").position().top;
        minusY = Math.sin(angle) * 4.0;
        plusX = Math.cos(angle) * 4.0;
        if(hitsWall(nowx+plusX, nowy-minusY)){
            clearInterval(ballMotion);
            shootball(newAngle(nowx+plusX, nowy-minusY), speed);
        }
        $("#ball").css("left", (nowx + plusX)).css("top", (nowy - minusY));
     }, 10/speed);
}
```

I'm not a big fan of big unnecessary recursion, but I just wanted to try it out.  Lo and behold it works exactly as I would expect.  But as I started fleshing out the rest of the program, it occurred to me that I had no way of avoiding this recursive nature.  So my question:  Does javascript somehow recognize that the calling "shootball" function is essentially finished after calling clearInterval?  Or does this really find itself loading up my stack with unnecessary activation records?  Thanks in advance for any expertise this may drum up.

Comment: You could set a break point and have a look at the callstack ;)

Comment: If a function takes longer to invoke than the interval, _setInterval_ can get nasty, consider using _setTimeout_ instead. Also, I'm sure you can move the majority of the function outside the expression so a new function instance isn't created each time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I believe that whenever the ball does not hit the wall the stack is emptied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does javascript somehow recognize that the calling "shootball" function is essentially finished after calling clearInterval?

No, `shootball` was finished long ago, right after the assignment to `ballmotion`. However, its variable scope (`angle`, `speed`, `ballmotion` and the parent scope) did persist since the anonymous function built a closure with it and was referenced from outside (from the scheduler). And that scope will get garbage collected after the `clearInterval` call which removed the references to it.

> does this really find itself loading up my stack with unnecessary activation records?

No. Every function that is executed via `setTimeout`/`setInterval` runs in its own execution context, with a brand new call stack.

Comment: The variables might not be necessarily cleared since in some browsers they will keep all the variables alive as long as the page is running.

Comment: @Derek: You mean some browsers screw up garbage collection of `clearInterval`?

Comment: I'm not sure but since I don't think it is written in the standards so the browser does not have to necessarily clear useless variables.