# Serially perform async task on messages from event listeners in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

If I have an event listener to any network connection where the underlying messages from the protocol are guaranteed to be ordered. It could be [NodeJS' net TCP socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) connection or a rabbitmq AMPQ connection with a high prefetch value.

I want to find a way to serially process them in the order that the messages arrive from the event listener.

Here's the rough sketch of the solution I've come up with exploiting NodeJS' single threaded event loop behaviour. I believe it will always work from a theoretical standpoint unless I've missed something.

Are they any drawbacks to this approach and can we do better? What I can see immediately is that the stack size of the recursive call can grow and exceed the limit if we receive a lot of messages in quick succession.

```
beingProcessed = false;
queue = new Queue(); // synchronous in memory queue 

.on("messageFromTCPSocketOrAMPQ", (msg) => { // sync callback
  // very important that the callback here does no async work prior to inserting into the 
  // queue to guarantee that the next message won't be pushed first
  queue.push(msg); // in memory queue
  processSerially(msg);
})

// sync function
processSerially() {
 if(beingProcessed || queue.size() === 0) {
   return;
 }
 beingProcessed = true;

 // this function can be made never throw depending on the use case
 doSomeTaskAsyncWithMessage(queue.pop(), () => {
   beingProcessed = false;
   // this recursive call in the callback is the reason why this works
   processSerially(); 
 })
}
```

Comment: If `doSomeTaskAsyncWithMessage` is actually asynchronous ([like setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24631041/1048572)), it [will not overflow the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29144361/1048572).

Comment: Yes, it's definition is `async doSomeTaskAsyncWithMessage(msg) {} ` let's say calling a database etc

Comment: If it's an `async` function and returns a promise, you shouldn't pass a callback though :-)

Comment: Ah, so I'd make `processSerially` async and then `await doSomeTask(msg)` followed by a pseudo recursive `unawaited processSerially`? Thanks, maybe you can answer the question and I'll accept it?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily make `processSerially` an `async` function, but at least write `doSomeTask(queue.pop()).catch(…).then(() => { beingProcessed = false; processSerially(); })`. However, if you *do* make it `async function processSerially`, you wouldn't even need (pseudo) recursion but could directly write a `while` loop.