# Non-recursive method to iterate over Promise iterator

Tags: javascript, promise

I've developed a client library that exposes a method called `iterator()`. This method returns a Promise instance created using `require('promise')` library, which is completed with an iterator object.

This object contains a method called `next()` which returns a Promise which is completed with a complex object like this: `{done: [true|false], key: _, value: _}`

Although `iterator()` might pre-fetch some elements, `next()` needs to return a Promise in case it results in a remote call.

Now, say a user wants to iterate over all elements until the Promise returned by `next()` returns an object containing `done: true`.

I've managed to achieve this using the following recursive method (I originally found this solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239036/186429)):

```js
var iterate = client.iterator();

iterateTeams.then(function(it) {

  function loop(promise, fn) {
    // Simple recursive loop over iterator's next() call
    return promise.then(fn).then(function (entry) {
      return !entry.done ? loop(it.next(), fn) : entry;
    });
  }

  return loop(it.next(), function (entry) {
    console.log('entry is: ' + entry);
    return entry;
  });

});
```

The question is, would it be possible, using `require('promise')` library, to build a non-recursive solution? The reason I'm interested in a non-recursive method is to avoid blowing up if the number of entries to iterate over is too big.

Cheers,
Galder

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a generator or observable.

Comment: you can use another solution which _hides_ the recursion for you but it still would be a recursive solution

Comment: Galder, you probably want to read the section entitled "The Collection Kerfuffle" [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/)

Comment: We're not there yet, but getting there :) See answer.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, thanks for the pointer but that section assumes you have an array or know how many elements you need to loop through and hence does not apply here.

Comment: [There is no reason why this would blow up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29925948/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi, could you add that as s solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason I'm interested in a non-recursive method is to avoid blowing up if the number of entries to iterate over is too big

Don't fear. Asynchronous "recursion" (sometimes dubbed [pseudo-recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876456/1048572)) does not grow the call stack, it's much like tail recursion. You won't ever get a stackoverflow exception.

And if the promise library is implemented reasonably, this should not even grow the memory - see [Building a promise chain recursively in javascript - memory considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29925948/1048572) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Without new syntax or a library - generally no.

Well, if you're using babel, you can use ES2018 (:P) async iteration:

```
for await (const team of iterateTeams) {
   // do something with team
}
```

[read more about it here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration)

Otherwise, you can use generators with ES2016 async/await syntax:

```
for(var it = iterateTeams(); !done; ({done, value}) = await it.next()) {
    // work with value
}
```

Or with available today ES2015 generator syntax and a pump through [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com):

```
// inside a Promise.corutine  
for(var it = iterateTeams(); !done; ({done, value}) = yield it.next()) {
   // work with value
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for those solutions but none of those work for me. I'm using ES2015 and require Node.js 0.10 (bluebird Promise.coroutine requires Node.js 0.12).

Comment: @GalderZamarreño how are you using ES2015 if you're using NodeJS 0.10?

Comment: Also, the answer still stands, without recursion or a helper method that does recursion itself - it's impossible before ES2015

Comment: Sorry, got confused, mean ES5 and Node.js 0.10.

Comment: Then no, you have to use recursion or a helper function that would use recursion itself - effectively extracting your `loop` function to a helper.